# converting date from Unix Epoch to YMD is adding an extra day

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have these two functions that format dates from `Ymd` (YYYYMMDD) to `U` (Unix Epoch date):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

function date_to_unix($date){
    // converts 20140526 - 1401062400
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date);
    return (int) $date->format('U');
}

function unix_to_date($unix){
    // converts 1401062400 - 20140526
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $unix);
    return (int) $date->format('Ymd');
}
```

And the unexpected results - starts as 25th, and ends as 26th:

```
$date = date("Ymd");
echo "date $date\n"; // date 20140525

$time = time();
echo "time $time\n"; // time 1401069030

$unix = date_to_unix($date);
echo "unix $unix\n"; // unix 1401069030

$date = unix_to_date($unix);
echo "date $date\n"; // date 20140526
```

Each time I use `unix_to_date` it seems to add an extra day,

Comment: Watch your time zones. 10pm on 25/May in New York is 2am on 26/May in London (or maybe 3am - I can never remember, but you get the point)

Comment: Thanks @MikeW - I do have `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` which I'll add to the question.

Comment: New York is 5 hours behind UTC so that's possible.

Comment: @wilsotc thanks! I subtracted `5*60*60 + 10` and that seems to fix it. (extra 10 for good luck)

Comment: That is not the correct thing to do!

Comment: @vascowhite I know! I just did that to prove the time zones were the issue. Now I pass in a timezone when I create the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP manual for `DateTime::create_from_format()`

> The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

This implies that when you create your DateTime object from a Unix timestamp (which is always UTC) that the new object is also UTC.

You'll need to set the timezone on the new object with [DateTime::setTimezone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to your local zone to get local time.

Since it is now around 10pm in New York a UTC time will be one day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as it stands it will give you some strange errors and your comment:-

> I subtracted 5*60*60 + 10 and that seems to fix it. (extra 10 for good luck)

indicates that you do not understand that you are doing this wrong, that (non) solution only compounds your errors.

Let's look at your `date_to_unix()` function first.

```
function date_to_unix($date){
    // converts 20140526 - 1401062400
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date);
    return (int) $date->format('U');
}
```

`$date` is a date string with the format 'Ymd' and you use it to create a DateTime object. Now, every DateTime object has a time component as well as a date component, which, if not specified defaults to the current system time. If you do not intend to use the time portion, I would suggest always setting it to 00:00:00 to avoid any strange results, but that is a personal preference and may not be necessary for your use case.

Having said that, this function seems fine, except that you want to return a timestamp as an int. Instead of casting from a string returned by DateTime::format() you could return the timestamp directly using DateTime::getTimestamp(), but that is being nit-picky:-

```
function date_to_unix($date){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date);
    return $date->getTimestamp();
}
```

Your second function is your real problem and is where your error lies.

```
function unix_to_date($unix){
    // converts 1401062400 - 20140526
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $unix);
    return (int) $date->format('Ymd');
}
```

You create the DateTime object directly from a unix timestamp and return its value. However, this DateTime instance is UTC and the purpose of your function is to return it to a local time, but you have missed that step, hence your error. You need to change the timestamp back to local time before returning:-

```
function unix_to_date($unix){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $unix);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
    return $date->format('Ymd');
}
```

The test of course, is that your functions can take a date, convert it to a timestamp and then convert that timestamp back to the same date. You can [see that working here](http://3v4l.org/P5Isv).

I hope this helps you.